# What is difference between JDK7u45 and Java7u21

Tags: java, java-7

I am starting with android development and while setting up Eclipse SDK i got an error that Java Development Kit(JDK) or Java Runtime Environment is missing. I had `Java7 update 21` installed already. but now I downloaded JDK7u45 from Oracle site.

I want to know the difference between `Java 7` and `JDK 7` and also if I remove JAVA and install only JDK(as EclipseSDK is giving an error that JDK is missing) then will it make any difference in my desktop environment?

Comment: However on a side note, while you can write code in Java 7, Android only supports upto Java 6 as per docs under System Requirements. http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Thanks for that notice @LotusUNSW. But installing a higher version will not support?

Comment: It will..but there are a few complications/problems. Googling this might help more here..

Comment: thank you @LotusUNSW. I will look in to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know the difference between Java 7 and JDK 7 and also if I
>   remove JAVA and install only JDK(as EclipseSDK is giving an error that
>   JDK is missing) then will it make any difference in my desktop
>   environment?

Java 7 = JDK7(Java Development Kit) + JRE7(Java Runtime Environment)

JDK 7 = just JDK i.e. Java Development Kit

JDK is required to compile/build your java programs, generates the class files. Whereas JRE is required to run the generated class files. Eclipse requires JDK to compile your code, hence it is necessary to have it. Generally JDK contains Java Runtime Environment under the directory name jre inside jdk.

Comment: Good elaboration Juned. I got rid of the prob `"JDK must be available in order to run Eclipse"` after installing JDK7u45 in local directory where i installed Eclipse. But now if i remove the Java7 (installed in Program Files) then will it make any problem?

Comment: @vishalkin Eclipse will look for JDK as per the JAVA_HOME environment variable, so if you set your JAVA_HOME to the JDK installed in eclipse dir and then uninstall the other java installation from "Program  Files" then you should be good.